# No connection pool with 'primary' found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, rails-activejob

I am using rails 5.2.3 and ruby 2.5.2 version , In my work i have two active job classes that will perform two jobs parallel , I am using MSSQL database and having "No connection pool with 'primary' found" issue when it started working in parallel .

Can anyone help me to resolve this .

Comment: Please post the contents of your `Gemfile`

Comment: I added the Gemfile below , I am using active jobs to work in parallel .

Answer (score 0):

```
#source 'https://rubygems.org'
source 'http://production.cf.rubygems.org'
#source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '5.2.3'
gem 'log4r'
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'bcrypt'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'activesupport'
gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter'
gem 'tiny_tds'
gem 'sequel'
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.5.2 '
gem 'bootsnap'
gem 'capybara'
gem 'poltergeist', :group => [:development, :test]
gem "rspec-rails", :group => [:development, :test]
gem 'public_suffix'
gem 'xpath'
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'byebug', '~> 11.1', '>= 11.1.1'
gem 'activewarehouse-etl', '~> 1.0'
gem 'table_print'
gem 'sidekiq'
#gem 'pg'
gem 'adapter_extensions', '~> 0.9.5.rc1'
gem 'test-unit'
gem "iconv", "~> 1.0.3"
gem 'fileutils'
gem 'json'
# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
gem 'stupidedi'
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'sass'
gem 'coffee-rails'
gem 'mailfactory'
gem 'rake'
gem 'rack-cache'
gem 'listen'
gem 'thor'
gem 'openssl'
gem 'rb-inotify'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
gem 'therubyrhino'

gem 'uglifier'
group :assets do

end
gem 'rubyzip', '>= 1.0.0' 

gem 'axlsx'
gem "axlsx_rails"
gem 'prawn'
gem 'typhoeus'
gem 'tlsmail'
gem 'net_http_ssl_fix'
gem 'simple_xlsx_reader'
gem 'spreadsheet'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
```